# how to show the response on page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```
...

index.html


    <body>
        <h1>upload test</h1>

        <!--<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/picture"> -->
        <form id="pictureForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <div>
           <label for="file">Choose file to upload</label>
           <input type="file" name="file" id="pictureFile"  multiple>
         </div>
         <div>
           <button>Submit</button>
         </div>
        </form>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./upload.js"></script>
    </body>
...
```

```
upload.js

...
    await axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/upload',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
    })
...
```

```
server.js

...
app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        const data = await fs.readFile('../index.html')
        res.write('Hello nodejs');
        res.end(data);
        next();
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        res.send('work');   <-- not working
    }
});
...
```

i'm making image upload server. and i success. i can upload image into particular directory that i want.

problem is, i want to see the phrase 'success' using res.end()(or res.send, etc). but web page was not change!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKWO6.png)

correctly, web got the response. but i don't know how to show this response on page.

please teach me.

Answer (score 0):

On the frontend you can do something like this

```
fetch("http://localhost:5500/upload", requestOptions).then(response => response.text())
```